# python-telegram-bot send_voice works on Android but not on IOS and Mac

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, chatbot, python-telegram-bot

I built a Telegram chatbot using `python-telegram-bot` library. The problem is with send voice message from the bot to the user. The voice message plays fine on Android but it doesn't on IOS and MacOS. Here is the code where I convert the audio file and send the voice message.

```
subprocess.call(["ffmpeg", "-n", "-i", telegram_username+"_response_audio.mp3", "-acodec", "aac", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "44100", telegram_username+"_response_audio.aac"])
await update.message.reply_voice(voice=open(telegram_username+"_response_audio.aac", 'rb'), reply_to_message_id=message_id, duration=audio_duration)
```

**Here is what I tried to fix it:**

- Since Telegram uses ogg/oga as default audio file format. So I tried to convert it into ogg format before sending the voice. But that didn't help.
- I also tried different audio formats and codecs. Nothing worked.

Would be grateful if someone point me in the right directions.
Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "voice message does not play fine on iOS/macOS"? Do you get a specific error message? What happens instead?

Comment: It just keeps loading the audio file

Comment: it = the client/TG app? Have you checked the return value of `update.message.reply_voice(…)`? If that gives a porper `Message` object, then it sounds like a client issue to me …

Comment: Have you found the solution? I've stuck with the same issue. I send voice as OGG after conversion from WAV, but on some clients (doesn't work on IOS and one Mac, and works on another Mac, one Linux and two Androids). As well in contrast to usual voice messages I can not see the spectrogram over such voice messages.